# jQuery "this" inside click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have something like

```
this.editElement = $("<a href='#'>Edit</a>").click(function() {
    this.startEdit();
});
```

This however takes "this" to be the editElement itself, rather than the parent object.

I've managed to get it to work by making a

```
var parent = this;
```

before setting click and then using parent enough of this.

Is this the correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is a common pattern.

Comment: This code looks complex; why not write simple-looking code instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very correct way, yes, and it's common.

You also took the right decision in naming it `parent` instead of the semantic-less `_this` we often see.

Other solutions :

- to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the callback to the external `this`
- to use the `data` argument of JQuery's `on` to pass the parent
- to dynamically find the parent from the callback

but most often referring to a variable kept in the external closure as you did is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Could you please provide some short examples, please?